# ScrollView con CardView no funciona

Tags: android, android-studio, xml, android-layout

Quiero usar un ScrollView para poner dentro unos CardView y un boton de forma vertical, hice este XML y si compila pero a la hora de probarlo en un dispositivo la app se cierra inmediatamente. El dispositivo en el cual estoy haciendo la prueba es API 22:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 

<ScrollView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.valenzuela.salvador.apuebacalculo.MainActivity">>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/seleccione"
    android:text="Seleccione el area de Calculo a estudiar:"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="12dp" />

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:onClick="uno"
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="223dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
    app:cardElevation="10dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/seleccione"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/diferencial" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="#8c000000"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Calculo Diferencial"
        android:textColor="#ffe3e3e3"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:onClick="dos"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="223dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
    app:cardElevation="10dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardView"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/integral" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="#8c000000"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Calculo Integral"
        android:textColor="#ffe3e3e3"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</ScrollView>
```

Este es mi gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.valenzuela.salvador.apuebacalculo"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
}
```

Comment: Que versión es tu dispositivo? Y pon tu gradle file

Comment: El de project o el de app?

Comment: De el app, no del proyecto

Comment: Listo ya agregue el gradle

Comment: En que version de dispositivo estas probandolo, puedes poner el log del error? Tu layout está en la carpeta /layout/ ?

Comment: La version es 5.1, el problema es que no hay ningun error, solo que la app se cierra al abrirla, cabe destacar que android studio si visualiza bien el layout

Comment: Revisa el logcat ahi esta la solucion y lo pones

Comment: Mira tu layout: MainActivity">> corrige ese doble >> y otra cosa muy importante, el scrollview solo puede tener dentro un contenedor ;) ahi veo que tienes un textview y cardview

Comment: Decir "la app se cierra inmediatamente" se puede deber a infinidad de causas, si deseas programar en android y no usas el LogCat para determinar un error, puedes tardar horas buscando un problema que puedes solucionar en segundos